# Unexpected behavior using ko.mapping.fromJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-3.0

I am experimenting with ko.mapping.fromJS
(http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Given the code below, and expectations, could someone explain to me why the actual output differs?

```
var obj = { name: "frederick", minions: [{id:1, name:'Alice'},{id:2, name:'Bob'}] }
var model = {
    'minions': {
        key: function(data) { return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id); }
    }
}

var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(obj, model);

vm.name.subscribe(x=>console.log("Changed name"));
vm.minions.subscribe(x => console.log("changed minions"));
vm.minions()[0].id.subscribe(x => console.log("changed id [0]"));
vm.minions()[0].name.subscribe(x => console.log("changed name [0]"));
vm.minions()[1].id.subscribe(x => console.log("changed id [1]"));
vm.minions()[1].name.subscribe(x => console.log("changed name [1]"));

obj.minions[0].name = 'Charlie';

ko.mapping.fromJS(obj, vm);
```

Expected logging:

```
changed name [0]
```

Actual logging:

```
changed name [0]
changed minions
```

Question:
Since there are no records added or removed to the array, why do I see "Changed minions"? Are these events always bubbled up, or only in case of arrays and direct child objects (/rows)?
(Or did I make a mistake in the model? Can I 'fix' this?)

Comment: Seems to be related to this issue: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/issues/187

Comment: PS: quote from GitHub on the knockout.mapping plugin: _Due to lack of time this project is currently not actively maintained._ (The last commit dates from 10 Jan 2014, the ticket mentioned in the comment above from 23 Jan 2014 ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening under the hood is this:

```js
var a = { a: 1 };
var b = { b: 2 };

var arr1 = [a, b];
var obsArray = ko.observableArray(arr2);
obsArray.subscribe(_ => console.log("change"));

var arr2 = [a, b];

// Logs change, since 
//  arr1 !== arr2
// even though:
//  arr1[0] === arr2[0] and
//  arr1[1] === arr2[1]
obsArray([a, b]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

I'd say the easiest way to counter this issue is to check for "equality" in your subscription method, but that's mainly because I don't know the mapping plugin very well...

How I'd solve it:

- Create a helper function that takes an `observableArray` and a callback function.
- The helper defines an `equalityCheck` that takes two arrays as input and returns `true` or `false`
- The helper creates a regular subscription to the observable but only calls the passed callback if the equality check passes.

To compare the new value that is passed to the knockout subscription with the previous one, it needs to store a reference to the previous value.

This means your syntax will change from:

```
vm.minions.subscribe(x => console.log("changed minions"));
```

to:

```
customSubscribe(vm.minions, x => console.log("changed minions"));
```

There might also be a way to fix this via the plugin or via an extender...

```js
const obsArraySubThatChecksInner = (arr, cb) => {
  let prevValues = arr();

  // Check if items are equal without checking the array reference
  const equalityCheck = (arr1, arr2) => {
    return arr1.length === arr2.length &&
      arr1.every((item, i) => item === arr2[i]);
  }

  return arr.subscribe(newValues => {
    // Make a copy to prevent mutations in cb
    const newArray = newValues.slice();

    if (!equalityCheck(prevValues, newValues)) {
      cb(newValues);
    };

    prevValues = newArray;
  });
};


var obsArr = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3]);

var regularSub = obsArr.subscribe(vals => console.log("Regular sub:", JSON.stringify(vals)));
var specialSub = obsArraySubThatChecksInner(
  obsArr, vals => console.log("Special sub:", JSON.stringify(vals))
);

// Is "similar", so will only trigger the regular sub.
obsArr([1, 2, 3]);

// Is different, so will trigger both
obsArr([1, 2]);
obsArr.push(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

With your data in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nk074pb3/